# Map/Filter in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a list.

```
[{name:"max", age:50}, {name:"sue", age: 43}, {name:"tom", age: 34}, {name:"tim", age: 33}]
```

Then I have another list that tells me what elements of the list with the persons I need to work on - I only need the age.

```
[false, true, true, false]
```

The result will be

```
[43, 34]
```

How can I get that in Typescript with a map/filter term? I am struggling with the index that tells what to take.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4VV4N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: What have you attempted and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index of [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return the boolean value of that item in the `filterArray` array. Then [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result to get a list of the ages only.

IMO it is not necessary to explicitely add typings anywhere. TypeScript is able to infer that result is of type `number[]` automatically.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "max", age: 50},
  {name: "sue", age: 43},
  {name: "tom", age: 34},
  {name: "tim", age: 33}
];

const filterArray = [false, true, true, false];

const result = data
  .filter((_, i) => filterArray[i])
  .map(person => person.age);

console.log(result); // Output: [43, 34]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you better to use `map` to merge the two lists into an array of objects containing names and ages, and then, employ `filter` to retain only the elements that align with `true` values in the second list! and lastly, utilize `map` once more to extract just the ages from the filtered list!

something like this:

```
const list = [{ name: "max", age: 50 }, { name: "sue", age: 43 }, { name: "tom", age: 34 }, { name: "tim", age: 33 }];
const filterList = [false, true, true, false];

const result = list
  .map((item, index) => ({ ...item, selected: filterList[index] }))
  .filter(item => item.selected)
  .map(item => item.age);

console.log(result); // [43, 34]
```

**update**
Yes thnx to @wonderflame, I optimized the code to avoid that extra iteration by combining the logic within a single `map` operation.

```
const list = [{ name: "max", age: 50 }, { name: "sue", age: 43 }, { name: "tom", age: 34 }, { name: "tim", age: 33 }];
const filterList = [false, true, true, false];

const result = list
  .map((item, index) => filterList[index] ? item.age : null)
  .filter(item => item !== null);

console.log(result); // [43, 34]
```

Comment: why make an extra iteration just for adding the `selected`?

Comment: again, you can optimize it more, just by filtering first, as I did in my comment

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper function `zip` to combine the two lists and then use reduce to get just the ages of the ones you want to keep:

```
const data = [{name:"max", age:50}, {name:"sue", age: 43}, {name:"tom", age: 34}, {name:"tim", age: 33}];
const keepers = [false, true, true, false];

const zip = <T, U>(as: T[], bs: U[]): [T, U][] => as.map((x, i) => [x, bs[i]]);

const ages = zip(data, keepers).reduce((ages, [{age}, keep]) => {
  if (keep) {
    ages.push(age);
  }

  return ages;
}, [] as number[]);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtA3mBBbAUwC4AiPBADxIBoYEBzYgVgAYBfWnfYkiAVwI06jIjAAsAZg4wuhUlBB4hDYjAljpsnlACWS2itESpAXQDcAKFCRYAawIEADgQBOENJgBmCADYQCtFAuAoHBATDefgTmFlbg0DAAXjqOHgA8ACq0AKoAfAAUCBCiGRgmtABGxTDZZQCUohhZNSZlaLl0EAB05I75+RS0OnXtmIMwVRg6JiZ1lnE2wgTu6Ml9iMi09k6uEHVdLgRwfMAE-SoQtNgq0tuOs6NYFjAwOp4w+XcjTy8vF12OPgQAAWhUYc2eMDYsRehygfBcYCWEEs0jaRRgYD4eAqrnqliAA)